# In JUnit, how can I get a list of all integration tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit, integration-testing, junit4

My integration tests run sequentially but i want to parallelize them.  Problem is, they all setup and teardown the same database row, so if they ran in parallel, their data would disappear in the middle of them using it when another test cleans up.

I plan change this by making it so that every test sets up and tears down a unique row per test so they don't interfere with each other.  I've started the process by turning every test's id into a constant of the same name, like `ROW_ID`.  But we've got a lot of tests, and it'd be easy to miss one of these and I also don't want people adding duplicate `ROW_ID` values in the future, so I figured it might be a good idea to write a test for my tests.

Here's how I imagine it'd work: Iterate all the IntegrationTest classes, use reflection to get the value of their `ROW_ID` field, put it in a data structure and then check for duplicates.  My problem is I don't know how to iterate all the IntegrationTest classes.  They all have a common naming pattern of "*IntegrationTest".  Can someone help me with that step?

And if there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, by all means give me that as an answer instead.

Comment: Instead of manually providing a row ID, why don't you use a database sequence instead?

Comment: @MarlonBernardes That's a good idea.  Maybe I can do that.

Comment: Or maybe create a thread-safe method which increments and returns an id counter. Something like `Long row_id = SequenceNumberGenerator.nextVal()`

Comment: @MarlonBernardes if you add this as an answer, I would vote it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of different options regarding the unique row id problem:

1. Use a database sequence instead of setting your ID's manually.
2. Implement a thread-safe counter and use it as your ROW_ID (see example below);

.

```
public class SequenceNumberGenerator {  

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();  

    public static int nextVal() {  
        return counter.incrementAndGet();
    }    
}
```

I also wouldn't create a constant ROW_ID in every test class (to avoid duplication). Instead, I think you could define it on a superclass (which would be extended by all integration tests), set it's value before the test execution and simply provide a getter accessor for it. Something like this:

```
//superclass
private int rowId;

@Before
public void generateRowId() {
    rowId = SequenceNumberGenerator.nextVal();
}

protected int getRowId() {
    return rowId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JUnit categories. Read [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/04/25/grouping-tests-using-junit-categories-0) webpage and maybe [this one](http://minds.coremedia.com/2012/08/30/experimenting-with-junit-categories/) as well. There are other frameworks which allow even better filtering (by package/including subpackages/including those starting with x/etc) but I can't remember the name of it... however, I think what you need is simple @Categories.

Comment: Are you referring to TestNG?

Comment: Also, this looks like a step in the right direction, but I don't know how to use the categories to get instances/classes of the tests in the category.

Comment: OK I looked it up, the framework is called [ClasspathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp). I haven't used it personally but my colleague says it's the best thing ever. As you'll see in the webpage, you can filter by any possible criteria you like, for example even by *IntegrationTest